# Interpreting regression coefficients when independent variables are aggregate scores

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, likert

I am using a service quality survey for my dissertation (Teeroovengadum et al., 2016 HESQUAL). My sample size is 138 (studied population appr. 1100) and thus I did a factor analysis of the 48 items. I got 10 factors total, which have different number of items in them. I was interested in running a regression analysis and comparing these factor's scores against satisfaction. But, since the factors have different max scores I figured that this should also affect to the interpretation of the coefficients.

All questions were rated on a 1-7 Likert scale, but the I ran the regression with factors that have 1-7 different items in them and thus the scores vary possibly from 1-7 to 7-49.

I speculated I could sidestep this interpretation issue by just using the average score of each factor(/dimension) instead of the max score. My question really is then, am I overlooking something here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you used factor analysis to get your ten scores?  Because saying the range of scores varies from 1-7 (for factor with 1 item) to 7-49 (for factor with 7 items) makes it sound like your "factors" sums of the items, rather than a weighted average which I'd expect from factor analysis.  If you used averages (weighted or not) instead of sums, your scores would be all be on the same 1-7 scale, although with differing variances.  Whether this is a good idea is another question though.

Comment: pl.. indicate your data anx output.